# apply a function to a groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I want to count how many consistent increase, and the difference between the first element and the last element, on a groupby. But I can't apply the function on the groupby. After groupby, is it a list? And also what's the difference between "apply" and "agg"? Sorry, I just touched the python for a few days.

```
def promotion(ls):
    pro =0
    if len(ls)>1:
        for j in range(1,len(ls)):
            if ls[j]>ls[j-1]:
                pro + = 1
    return pro
def growth(ls):
    head= ls[0]
    tail= ls[len(ls)-1]
    gro= tail-head
    return gro
titlePromotion= JobData.groupby("candidate_id")["TitleLevel"].apply(promotion)
titleGrowth= JobData.groupby("candidate_id")["TitleLevel"].apply(growth)
```

The data is:

```
candidate_id    TitleLevel     othercols
1                 2              foo
2                 1              bar
2                 2              goo
2                 1              gar
The result should be
titlePromotion
candidate_id 
1                  0
2                  1
titleGrowth
candidate_id
1               0
2               0
```

Comment: I'm sure we've all "touched the python" a few times. . .

Comment: Welcome to python community! In a neat @unutbu answer you can find a part with sample data generation and testing (`jobData = pd.DataFrame(...)` and following). To make your future questions, if any, even better and easier to answer,  I strongly advise you to provide similar code for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

def promotion(ls):
    return (ls.diff() > 0).sum()

def growth(ls):
    return ls.iloc[-1] - ls.iloc[0]

jobData = pd.DataFrame(
    {'candidate_id': [1, 2, 2, 2],
     'TitleLevel': [2, 1, 2, 1]})

grouped = jobData.groupby("candidate_id")
titlePromotion = grouped["TitleLevel"].agg(promotion)
print(titlePromotion)
# candidate_id
# 1               0
# 2               1
# dtype: int64

titleGrowth = grouped["TitleLevel"].agg(growth)
print(titleGrowth)
# candidate_id
# 1               0
# 2               0
# dtype: int64
```

---

Some tips:

If you define the generic function

```
def foo(ls):
    print(type(ls))
```

and call

```
jobData.groupby("candidate_id")["TitleLevel"].apply(foo)
```

Python will print

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

This is a low-brow but effective way to discover that calling `jobData.groupby(...)[...].apply(foo)` passes a `Series` to `foo`.

---

The `apply` method calls `foo` once for every group. It can return a Series or a DataFrame with the resulting chunks glued together. It is possible to use `apply` when `foo` returns an object such as a numerical value or string, but in such cases I think using `agg` is preferred. A typical use case for using `apply` is when you want to, say, square every value in a group and thus need to return a new group of the same shape.

The `transform` method is also useful in this situation -- when you want to *transform* every value in the group and thus need to return something of the same shape -- but the result can be different than that with `apply` since a different object may be passed to `foo` (for example, each column of a grouped dataframe would be passed to `foo` when using `transform`, while the entire group would be passed to `foo` when using `apply`. The easiest way to understand this is to experiment with a simple dataframe and the generic `foo`.)

The `agg` method calls `foo` once for every group, but unlike `apply` it should return a single number per group. The group is *aggregated* into a value. A typical use case for using `agg` is when you want to count the number of items in the group.

---

You can debug and understand what went wrong with your original code by using the generic `foo` function:

```
In [30]: grouped['TitleLevel'].apply(foo)
0    2
Name: 1, dtype: int64
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    1
2    2
3    1
Name: 2, dtype: int64
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Out[30]: 
candidate_id
1               None
2               None
dtype: object
```

This shows you the Series that are being passed to `foo`. Notice that in the second Series, then index values are 1 and 2. So `ls[0]` raises a `KeyError`, since there is no label with value `0` in the second Series.

What you really want is the first item in the Series. That is what `iloc` is for.

So to summarize, use `ls[label]` to select the row of a Series with index value of `label`. Use `ls.iloc[n]` to select the `n`th row of the Series.

Thus, to fix your code with a the least amount of change, you could use

```
def promotion(ls):
    pro =0
    if len(ls)>1:
        for j in range(1,len(ls)):
            if ls.iloc[j]>ls.iloc[j-1]:
                pro += 1
    return pro
def growth(ls):
    head= ls.iloc[0]
    tail= ls.iloc[len(ls)-1]
    gro= tail-head
    return gro
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! You gave a very detailed explanation. But can you do me an another favor to explain why my code runs wrong? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
VAR0    VAR1
1       1 
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       5
2       6
2       7
2       8
```

you could jus use lambda in apply like that:

the code below would substract all values from the first one

```
grp = df.groupby('VAR0')['VAR1'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] - x)
```

if you try that with agg:

```
grp = df.groupby('VAR0')['VAR1'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[0] - x)
```

it won't work because agg needs to get one value for each group

if you subtract values of a particular cells, there's no difference between agg and apply, they both create a one value for each group

```
grp = df.groupby('VAR0')['VAR1'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] - x.iloc[-1])
grp = df.groupby('VAR0')['VAR1'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[0] - x.iloc[-1])

print grp

VAR0
1      -3
2      -3
Name: VAR1, dtype: int64
```

if you would like for example substract each row value from the previous row (to get the increment for each row), you could use transform like that:

```
grp = df.groupby('VAR0')

def subtr(x):
    y=x.copy()
    for i in range(1,len(x.index)):
        x.iloc[i]=y.iloc[i]-y.iloc[i-1]
    return x

new_var = grp['VAR1'].transform(subtr)
print new_var

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    5
5    1
6    1
7    1
Name: VAR1, dtype: int64
```

or more easily, for this particular problem:

```
grp = df.groupby('VAR0')['VAR1'].apply(lambda x: x - x.shift())
```