# Flag outliers in the dataframe for each group

Tags: python, pandas, apply, pandas-groupby

I would like to identify outliers for each group of values within a dataframe and return a dataframe with a column containing True/False for each row of the dataframe.

```
data = {'Group':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18, 2, 17]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

def flag_outlier(x):
    lower_limit  = np.mean(x) - np.std(x) * 3 
    upper_limit = np.mean(x) + np.std(x) * 3
    for i in x:
        if i > upper_limit or i < lower_limit:
            return True
df['Flag'] = df.groupby('Group')['Age'].apply(flag_outlier)
```

This code return a column with NaN, how can this function be fixed?

This post 
[apply a function to a groupby function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153307/apply-a-function-to-a-groupby-function) is similar, but I cannot figure out.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your function to the folllowing,

```py
def flag_outlier(x):
    lower_limit  = np.mean(x) - np.std(x) * 3 
    upper_limit = np.mean(x) + np.std(x) * 3
    return (x>upper_limit)| (x<lower_limit)
```

because the way you are going about it, your function returns just one value per group

Comment: I accepted this answer because it is more similar to my original solution, but the other answer is great too. Thank you all

Comment: Though I appreciate your sentiment, being closer to your answer is not a metric for goodness... in general.  The other answer sticks to using existing pandas API and should be rather efficient.  This answer is fine but in my opinion, the other is better.  I'm writing this for the benefit of everyone who might view this question and answers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `groupby().transform` to get `mean` and `std` by group, then `between` to find outliers:

```
groups = df.groupby('Group')
means = groups.Age.transform('mean')
stds = groups.Age.transform('std')

df['Flag'] = df.Age.between(means-stds*3, means+stds*3)
```

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks.

Comment: The outliers will have the flag "False" right?

Comment: @Rod0n yes. That’s correct