# Flagging outliers in dataframe, creating a new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

I see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57256870/flag-outliers-in-the-dataframe-for-each-group) and want to update it slightly.

```
data = {'Group':['A', 'A', 'A'], 'Age':[18, 200, 17]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to create a new column 'Outlier`, where the outlier will be flagged as true or false based on 3 standard deviations.

My desired output

```
data = {'Group':['A', 'A', 'A'], 'Age':[18, 200, 17], 'Outlier':['False', 'True', 'False']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

Comment: The mean is 78.33 and standard deviation is 105.37. All values are within 3 standard deviations. How do you get a "True" for age 200?

Comment: I believe the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57256962/536503 is correct. As is the comment of not_speshal above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `groupby` and `transform`:

```
zscores = df.groupby('Group').transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())
df["Outlier"] = zscores.abs()>3

>>> df
  Group  Age  Outlier
0     A   18    False
1     A  200    False
2     A   17    False
```

To get outliers regardless of the group, use:

```
zscores = (df["Age"]-df["Age"].mean())/df["Age"].std()
df["Outlier"] = zscores.abs()>3
```

Comment: how would update this code without gropby? How to check just based on numeric column? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Just with Age column. data = {'Age':[18, 200, 17]}. If I do not want to group, but identify outliers and create a new True/False column.

Comment: I have multiple numeric columns and want to create a separate new column for each numeric column with True/False as above